# Getting complete objects from CouchDB after map/reduce

Tags: couchdb

in this example http://guide.couchdb.org/draft/cookbook.html#unique the output rows are grouped to achieve uniqueness, but the value attribute contains only data defined in the reduce step. Is there an efficient way to get the complete objects as values?

Another way would be getting the ids of the objects as values after reduce and query the complete objects in a second step. How would you design the corresponding map/reduce functions in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want "?include_docs=true".

check it out here..

http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/HTTP_view_API#Querying_Options